# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'interface'

Tags: python, can-bus

I keep getting this error when setting up a canopen Connection
My Code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('venv/Lib/site-packages')
import canopen

network = canopen.Network()
network.connect(bustype='socketcan', channel='can0', bitrate=250000)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\CanProjekt\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    network.connect(bustype='socketcan', channel='can0', bitrate=250000)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\CanProjekt\venv\lib\site-packages\canopen\network.py", line 112, in connect
    self.bus = can.interface.Bus(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'interface'
```

Why is that?
Thanks in advance.

i tried this on my Linux maschine connected to Can divices and also on my Windows PC with a CanModul

network.Connect method:

```
def connect(self, *args, **kwargs) -> "Network":
    """Connect to CAN bus using python-can.

    Arguments are passed directly to :class:`can.BusABC`. Typically these
    may include:

    :param channel:
        Backend specific channel for the CAN interface.
    :param str bustype:
        Name of the interface. See
        `python-can manual <https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#interface-names>`__
        for full list of supported interfaces.
    :param int bitrate:
        Bitrate in bit/s.

    :raises can.CanError:
        When connection fails.
    """
    # If bitrate has not been specified, try to find one node where bitrate
    # has been specified
    if "bitrate" not in kwargs:
        for node in self.nodes.values():
            if node.object_dictionary.bitrate:
                kwargs["bitrate"] = node.object_dictionary.bitrate
                break
    self.bus = can.interface.Bus(*args, **kwargs)
    logger.info("Connected to '%s'", self.bus.channel_info)
    self.notifier = can.Notifier(self.bus, self.listeners, 1)
    return self
```

Comment: Do you have python-can installed?

Comment: Yes, it's installed. that why im woundering

Comment: Just add a `import can` at the top of your script and see what happens